# Characterization of $AB=BA$ in terms of the spectral measure

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb C$-Hilbert space, $A\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be self-adjoint and $B\in\mathfrak L(H)$.

If $\xi_A$ is the spectral measure associated with $A$, I would like to show that $A$ and $B$ commute iff $\xi_A(I)$ and $B$ commute for all $I\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

For simplicity, I would like to assume $\dim H\in\mathbb N$. Letting $\pi_A(\lambda)$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $E_A(\lambda):=\mathcal N(\lambda-A)$, the desired claim should become:

1. $AB=BA$;
2. $\pi_A(\lambda)B=B\pi_A(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}$.

Since we can write $$A=\sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}}\lambda\pi_A(\lambda)\tag1,$$ it is clear that (2.) implies (1.).

But I really struggle to show the converse.

Assume $(1.)$. Let $x\in H$ and $\lambda\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}$. Maybe it's helpful to consider the cases $x\in E_A(\lambda)$ and $x\not\in E_A(\lambda)$ separately. In the first case, $$B\pi_A(\lambda)x=BAx=ABx=\sum_{\mu\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{0\}}\pi_A(\mu)Bx\tag2.$$ However, I've don't know how we can show that the right-hand side is equal to $\pi_A(\lambda)Bx$ ...

Comment: $x \in E_A(\lambda)$ means $Ax = \lambda x$. Then $ABx=BAx=\lambda Bx$. Hence $Bx \in E_A(\lambda)$, and therefore $\pi_A(\mu)Bx = 0$ for $\mu \not= \lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are staying in the finite-dimensional case, you can do the following.

From $AB=BA$ you can easily get $A^nB=BA^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. It then follows that $p(A)B=Bp(A)$ for all $p\in\mathbb C[x]$.

Now with a fixed $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$ (doesn't matter if it is nonzero), since $\sigma(A)$ is finite you can choose a polynomial $p$ such that $p(\lambda)=1$ and $p(\eta)=0$ for all $\eta\in\sigma(A)\setminus\{\lambda\}$. Then
$$
p(A)=\sum_{\alpha\in\sigma(A)}p(\alpha)\,\pi_A(\alpha)=\pi_A(\lambda) 
$$
and
$$
\pi_A(\lambda)B=p(A)B=Bp(A)=B\pi_A(\lambda). 
$$
The same idea can be used in infinite dimension but it requires the Borel functional calculus and to restate your problem a bit since $A$ may not have any eigenvalues.